# OpenCV: Accessing And Taking The Square Root Of Pixels

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I'm using OpenCV for object detection and one of the operations I would like to be able to perform is a per-pixel square root. I imagine the loop would be something like:

```
IplImage* img_;
...
for (int y = 0; y < img_->height; y++) {
  for(int x = 0; x < img_->width; x++) {
    // Take pixel square root here
  }
}
```

My question is how can I access the pixel value at coordinates (x, y) in an IplImage object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming img_ is of type IplImage, and assuming 16 bit unsigned integer data, I would say

```
unsigned short pixel_value = ((unsigned short *)&(img_->imageData[img_->widthStep * y]))[x];
```

See also [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/basic_structures.html#id1) for IplImage definition.

Comment: Thanks, this definitely helped :)

Comment: And I even don't know OpenCV at all :)

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV IplImage is a one dimensional array. You must create a single index to get at image data. The position of your pixel will be based on the color depth, and number of channels in your image.

```
// width step 
int ws = img_->withStep;
// the number of channels (colors)
int nc = img_->nChannels;
// the depth in bytes of the color 
int d = img_->depth&0x0000ffff) >> 3;
//  assuming the depth is the size of a short
unsigned short * pixel_value = (img_->imageData)+((y*ws)+(x*nc*d));
// this gives you a pointer to the first color in a pixel
//if your are rolling grayscale just dereference the pointer.
```

You can pick a channel (color) by moving over pixel pointer pixel_value++. I would suggest using a look up table for square roots of pixels if this is going to be any sort of real time application.

Answer (score 1):

please use the CV_IMAGE_ELEM macro.
Also, consider using cvPow with power=0.5 instead of working on pixels yourself, which should be avoided anyways

Answer (score 0):

You may find several ways of reaching image elements in Gady Agam's nice OpenCV tutorial [here](http://www.cs.iit.edu/~agam/cs512/lect-notes/opencv-intro/opencv-intro.html#SECTION00053000000000000000).

Comment: Unfortunately, the link is not accessible.