# Find pixel color out of cv::Mat on specific position

Tags: opencv, colors, matrix, pixel

well my problem is, I need to find the sub matrix of a cv::Mat image which includes all white pixels. Therefore I want to iterate through all pixels, check if they are white and build a cv::Rect with that information.
I figured out how to iterate through all the pixels but I don't know how to get the pixels color out of it. The cv::Mat was previously converted to greyscale with `CV_GRAY2BGR`

```
for(int y = 0; y < outputFrame.rows; y++)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < outputFrame.cols; x++)
    {
        // I don't know which datatype I should use
        if (outputFrame.at<INSERT_DATATYPE_HERE>(x,y) == 255)
           //define area
    }
}
```

My final question is, which datatype should I insert in the code on the position INSERT_DATATYPE_HERE and is 255 the right value to compare with than?

Thanks alot

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cycle through pixels with opencv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504687/cycle-through-pixels-with-opencv)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on your image's channels. [Mat](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html#mat) has method `channels`. It returns number of channels - it's **one** if image is gray, **three** if image is color (for example, RGB - one channel for each color component).

So you have to do something like this:

```
if (outputFrame.channels() == 1) //image is grayscale - so you can use uchar (1 byte) for each pixel
{
    //...
    if (outputFrame.at<uchar>(x,y) == 255)
    {
        //do a check if this pixel is the most left, or the most right, or the most top, or the most bottom (this is needed to construct result rectangle)
    }
}
else
if (outputFrame.channels() == 3) //image is color, so type of each pixel if Vec3b
{
    //...
    // white color is when all values (R, G and B) are 255
    if (outputFrame.at<Vec3b>(x,y)[0] == 255 && outputFrame.at<Vec3b>(x,y)[1] == 255 && outputFrame.at<Vec3b>(x,y)[2] == 255)
    {
        //do a check if this pixel is the most left, or the most right, or the most top, or the most bottom (this is needed to construct result rectangle)
    }
}
```

But actually to get rectangle which contains all white pixels on image you can use another technique:

1. [Convert image to grayscale](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/miscellaneous_image_transformations.html#cv-cvtcolor).
2. Do a [threshold](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/miscellaneous_image_transformations.html#cv-threshold) with value 254 (or near 255) as parameter.
3. [Find all contours on image](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.2/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html).
4. Construct one contour that contains all these contours (simply adding all points of each contour into one big contour).
5. Use [bounding rectangle function](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#cv-boundingrect) to find needed for you rectangle.

Comment: the channel == 1 seems to work, unfortunately is the `if (outputFrame.at<uchar>(y,x) == 255)` always true, do you have an idea to solve that one?

Comment: You have white image than. Post it. And also why `(y,x)` not `(x,y)`?

Comment: worked, I'm stupid, the first frame was always white, but since the cout of every pixel was extremely slow i never waited till the first frame was processed. Thanks a lot! I will try the contour detection as well. Thanks again